# Can I use path variable in spring controller class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can I use path variable for spring controller class?

I know that we can use path variables in controller's methods. In the same fashion can we use it for entire class?
Eg:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "{version}/test")
class TestController {

}
```

Can we use like this? If yes how do we read `{version}` variable? Actually i need this kind of approach, based on the version i'll respond. If the above approach is not possible can you please suggest me a design to solve this problem?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes you can. Just declare it as @PathVariable in your methods if you want to access it there.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "{version}/test")
class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/something")
    public ModelAndView doSomething(@PathVariable String version) {
       // do something here with the version
    }

}
```