# Swagger - add "path variable" in request url

Tags: java, swagger

I'm using Swagger and I'm trying to add a custom path variable.

One of my endpoint looks like:

```
http://localhost:8008/schools/{schoolId}/teachers/{teacherId}
```

Where my controller looks like:

```java
{
    @RestController
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @RequestMapping("/schools/{schoolId}/teachers")
    public class TeacherController {
    
        private final TeacherRepository teacherRepository;
    
        @GetMapping("/{teacherId}")
        public Teacher get(@PathVariable Long teacherId) {
            return teacherRepository.findById(teacherId);
        }
}
```

`teacherId` is obviously `pathVariable`, so swagger can add a placeholder for it, but `schoolId` for swagger is not, so when I process any endpoint I get:

```
http://localhost:8008/schools/%7BschoolId%7D/teachers/{teacherId}
```

Is it possible to somehow replace this value in swagger? `schoolId` is used in filter to change the database automatically based on `schoolId` so I don't handle it in controller

Answer (score 0):

That's because the schoolId path variable cannot be resolved by Spring.

The solution is to do add it to the get method:

```
@GetMapping("/{teacherId}")
@ApiOperation("Get all teachers")
public Teacher get(@PathVariable String schoolId, @PathVariable Long teacherId) {
    return teacherRepository.findById(teacherId);;
}
```

Now swagger will detect is as a path variable on controller level, and it will be shown correctly in your swagger-api-docs

See an example of how to use path variables on controller level and how to acces them: [How to access a PathVariable of a controller specified at class level in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236441/how-to-access-a-pathvariable-of-a-controller-specified-at-class-level-in-spring)