# How to simplify the request mappings of these controllers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, request-mapping

I've a controller class with the following signature:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home/users")
public class MaterialsController { ... }
```

and every method in this controller class starts with the same path variable, that is, `{username}`, for example, I've the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{username}/mycreations/{coursewareName}/materials/{materialId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteCourseMaterialFromCreatedCourseware(@PathVariable String username,
        @PathVariable String coursewareName, @PathVariable String materialId, Model model,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

Now, it's a little bit tedious to write `{username}` at the beginning of each of these controller's methods. Is there a way to specify this path variable at class level? Of course I also need to access it then, like in the same way I'm specifying `@PathVariable String username` in the method above.

Also, I ideally, I would like also to include at class-level more than one variable, when necessary.

Comment: You can move the path to the class level yes, but not the parameters.

Comment: So, for example, I could have at class level the following path `/home/users/{username}`, and then at method level having just `mycreations/{coursewareName}/materials/{materialId}"`, but still keeping the `@PathVariable String username` at method level?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put it at the class level, but you have to include it in the path variable in the appropriate methods.

[Can I use path variable in spring controller class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980597/can-i-use-path-variable-in-spring-controller-class)