# How to use path variable in a spring controller class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I [have seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980597/can-i-use-path-variable-in-spring-controller-class) that I can use path variables in a Requestmapping annotation defined above the class itself.
However, I can't make it work. What am I missing here?

My controller class:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "{conncetion_name}/widget")
public class WidgetController {

private PortsRepository portsRepository;
private PortsService portsService;

@Autowired
public WidgetController(PortsRepository portsRepository, PortsService portsService) {
    this.portsRepository = portsRepository;
    this.portsService = portsService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getBulkdata")
public List<TransferObject> getBulkData(@PathVariable(value="connection_name") String connectionName){

    return portsService.convertPortsToTransferObject(portsRepository.findByroomTypeIsNotNull());

}
}
```

When I try to reach the given url I get an error message saying:

```
Sat May 13 17:47:05 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Missing URI template variable 'connection_name' for method parameter of type String
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Check your code very closely... Compare both the names... (Or to give you a closer hint `conncetion_name` != `connection_name`).

Comment: Thx m8, you are obviously right!

Answer (score 1):

Requestmapping annotation for path variable :-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cities")
public class CityController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CityController.class);

@Autowired
private CityService cityService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RestResponse find(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
.
.
.   
}
```

or you can use also like this : -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<City> find(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
.
.
.   
}
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding example corresponding URI/HTTP requests that map to the controller endpoints you've specified above.